# MaySQL InnoDB cluster log fill on one server

Tags: mysql, innodb, clustering, logging

in my mysqld.cnf file, I enabled logging via the following

```
general_log         = 1
general_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

It is a three-node cluster.  I can see all the queries in the log file, however, one server has a much larger file size, several hundred MB over the others.  when I tail the log, I see a lot of the following over and over again.

```
2023-12-04T18:41:37.297122-05:00        134678 Query    SELECT * FROM mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.schema_version
2023-12-04T18:41:37.297685-05:00        134678 Query    select cluster_type from mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.v2_this_instance
2023-12-04T18:41:37.299652-05:00        134678 Query    select count(clusterset_id) from mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.v2_this_instance i join mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.v2_cs_members csm on i.cluster_id = csm.cluster_id where clusterset_id is not null
2023-12-04T18:41:37.301627-05:00        134678 Query    SELECT member_state FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members WHERE CAST(member_id AS char ascii) = CAST(@@server_uuid AS char ascii)
2023-12-04T18:41:37.301991-05:00        134678 Query    SELECT SUM(IF(member_state = 'ONLINE', 1, 0)) as num_onlines, COUNT(*) as num_total FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members
2023-12-04T18:41:37.302278-05:00        134678 Query    select C.cluster_id, C.cluster_name, I.mysql_server_uuid, I.endpoint, I.xendpoint, I.attributes from mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.v2_instances I join mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.v2_gr_clusters C on I.cluster_id = C.cluster_id where C.group_name = '66566db6-8f02-11ee-8106-f23c940aadab'
2023-12-04T18:41:37.302745-05:00        134678 Query    select count(clusterset_id) from mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.v2_this_instance i join mysql_innodb_cluster_metadata.v2_cs_members csm on i.cluster_id = csm.cluster_id where clusterset_id is not null
2023-12-04T18:41:37.304120-05:00        134678 Query    COMMIT
2023-12-04T18:41:37.304360-05:00        134678 Query    show status like 'group_replication_primary_member'
2023-12-04T18:41:37.305040-05:00        134678 Query    SELECT member_id, member_host, member_port, member_state, @@group_replication_single_primary_mode FROM performance_schema.replication_group_members WHERE channel_name = 'group_replication_applier'
```

why is it not even across all nodes?

Other posts suggest using the slow log to capture the queries which is OK, but ideally I would like to understand why one node appears to be doing a lot of work.

Comment: Are you writing only to that one node?  Is there a monitoring service that is probing that node?

Comment: On a three-node cluster, there is one which is the "manager", so it will log a lot of cluster related queries, just like those you posted.

Comment: sorry all, did not see these responses. Yes.  MYSQL router is used to determine cluster health and which is write/read.